# Multiple functions using property assignment possible?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

According to [this article](http://www.bryanbraun.com/2014/11/27/every-possible-way-to-define-a-javascript-function) by Bryan Braun outlining the different possible ways to write functions in Javascript, Property Assignment is a method of doing so. His example is similar to this:

```
var obj1 = {
  SetName: function() {
    obj1.name = "Programmer_Frank";
  }
};
```

and this can be called as such:

```
obj1.SetName();
```

This works properly. It gives me an object with a member `"name"` and a value `"Programmer_Frank"`.

However, when I try:

```
var obj1 = {
  SetName: function() {
    obj1.name = "Programmer_Frank";
  }

  SetAddress: function(theAddress) {
    obj1.address = theAddress;
  }
};
```

and you would reference these functions as such:

```
obj1.SetName();
obj1.SetAddress("P Sherman 42 Wallaby Way");
```

which gives me an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in the developers' debugger in Chrome on the line `SetAddress: function(theAddress) {`.
Why is that? Is it just impossible to use property assignment for 2 functions? Here is my full code, it is just a tester app so it isn't much more than what I've posted so far, but maybe it will be still useful to have the full code posted.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var obj1 = {
  SetName: function() {
    obj1.name = "Programmer_Frank";
  }

  SetAddress: function(theAddress) {
    obj1.address = theAddress;
  }
};

</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>

obj1.SetName();
obj1.SetAddress("P Sherman 42 Wallaby Way");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" is about as informative as one could hope. Various linters would produce similar messages. You could stare at `setAddress` and try to deduce why you would get an unexpected identifier, and perhaps eventually figure out that it was the missing comma. You could also use the divide and conquer approach: first remove the body of `SetAddress`, then change it to `SetAddress: 42`, then change it to `x: 42`, and eventually it might dawn on you that you had left out the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma after the first method definition

```
var obj1 = {
  SetName: function() {
    obj1.name = "Programmer_Frank";
  }, //this comma
  SetAddress: function(theAddress) {
    obj1.address = theAddress;
  }
};
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! Would of never guessed.

Comment: It's a mystery why you would never have guessed that, since commas between key/value pairs in JS object literals is one of the fundamentals of the language.